# Powershell Script to BackUp and Copy TNSNames.ora file on Local folder

Tags: powershell, copy, sccm

I'm trying to fix a script and it seems that I lost the thread here. I'm always getting a result of Success on my log file, is kind of a great result to be honest but even if I delete the source folder it gets a Success :(.

I'm not a coder, but I got some functions to be working, the function that still doesn't works is the following:
1- When the Source folder or file doesn't exists, then it supposed to create a registry entry with a Fail value, so SCCM will take it as detection Method to evaluate the deployment and also write it the the log file: C:\logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0.log

Here you are my code, and feel free to use it as it works fine copying the file from a network share and it will create a backup with a Timestamp on it, of course once is fixed:

```
# Function

Function writetolog ($nTxt){ 
$date = Get-Date
$sapce = '    '
$log_path = 'C:\logs\'
$log_name = $log_path + 'CopyTNSNames_1.0.log'
if(!(Test-Path -Path $log_path )){New-Item -ItemType directory -Path  $log_path}
Add-content $log_name -value $date$sapce$nTxt
}
Function code_retour ($rc){
$date = Get-Date
$rc_ok = 0,3010
$Script_returnCode = 0
$CodeDeRetour = "Return code : ",$rc
if($rc_ok -contains $rc){
writetolog $CodeDeRetour
return $rc
}Else{
writetolog $CodeDeRetour
writetolog 'The script has failed'
writetolog ''
writetolog "**************************"
writetoreg ('Fail',$rc)
exit $rc} 
}
Function writetoreg($status){ 
$date = Get-Date
$status_rc = 'RC = ' + $status[1]
$regpath_MyCompany = 'hklm:software\MyCompany'
$regpath_Tier = 'hklm:software\MyCompany\Applications'
$regpath_App = 'hklm:software\MyCompany\Applications\CopyTNSNames_1.0'
$regpath_DT = 'hklm:software\MyCompany\Applications\CopyTNSNames_1.0\Result'
if(!(Test-Path $regpath_MyCompany)){New-Item -Path $regpath_MyCompany}
if(!(Test-Path $regpath_Tier)){New-Item -Path $regpath_Tier}
if(!(Test-Path $regpath_App)){New-Item -Path $regpath_App}
if(!(Test-Path $regpath_DT)){New-Item -Path $regpath_DT}
If($status[0] -eq 'Succes'){
$result = 'Succes'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath_DT -Name $result -Value $date}
If($status[0] -eq 'Failure'){
$result = 'Failure Timestamp ' + $date 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath_DT -Name $result -Value $status_rc}
}

cls

   Function CopyOra
   {
    $PathFolder = "\\partage\ORAFiles\Source"
    $DestinationFolder = "c:\Apps\Oracle\11.2\network\admin\"


    if (!(test-path $DestinationFolder))
{
  New-Item $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory
  "$(Get-Date) : Created folder  $DestinationFolder" | Out-File "C:\Logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0" -Append
}


$Dir = get-childitem $PathFolder | Sort-Object Time -descending
$LOGFilesFound = $Dir | where { $_.extension -eq ".ora" }

"$(Get-Date) : processing files: $LOGFilesFound" | Out-File "C:\Logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0" -Append

write-host "$(Get-Date) : processing files: $LOGFilesFound"

foreach ($LOGFile in $LOGFilesFound) 
{

    write-host $PathFolder\$LOGFile

    Try 
    {
        If ( Test-Path $DestinationFolder$LOGFile) 
        {
            "$(Get-Date) : fichier trouvé $DestinationFolder$LOGFile ... Copie de backup en cours." | Out-File "C:\Logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0" –Append

            $now=Get-Date -format "dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm"
            $newFileName = "$LOGFile-$now"

            copy-item -path "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile" -destination "$DestinationFolder$newFileName" -Container -Force:$true -Recurse

            "$(Get-Date) : $DestinationFolder$newFileName créé." | Out-File "C:\Logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0" –Append

        } else
        {
            write-host "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile non trouvé sur le poste"
            "$(Get-Date) : $DestinationFolder$newFileName non trouvé localement." | Out-File "C:\Logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0" –Append
        }

        copy-item -path "$PathFolder\$LOGFile" -destination "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile" -Container -Force:$true -Recurse
        "$(Get-Date) : Copy done $PathFolder\$LOGFile" | Out-File "C:\Logs\CopyTNSNames_1.0" –Append
    }
    Catch
        {
            "$(Get-Date) : copie non possible..." | Out-File "C:\Logs\" –Append
            $Script_returnCode = code_retour $returnCode.ExitCode
            write-host $returnCode.ExitCode
           }
    }

}



#Run main function
CopyOra 


writetolog ""
writetolog "End of script"
writetolog "**************************"
writetoreg ("Success",$Script_returnCode)
exit $Script_returnCode
```

Hope you can help me to solve this issue.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have rebuild you script for intercept error correctly, always use log function and remove unnecessary code

try this :

```
Function writetolog ($nTxt){ 
$log_path = 'C:\logs\'
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path  $log_path -Force | Out-Null

$log_Text="{0}    {1}" -f (Get-Date), $nTxt
$log_name = $log_path + 'CopyTNSNames_1.0.log'
Add-content $log_name -value $log_Text 
}

Function code_retour ($rc){
$rc_ok = 0
$CodeDeRetour = "Return code : $rc"

if($rc_ok -eq $rc)
{
    writetolog $CodeDeRetour
    writetoreg ("Success",$rc)
    writetolog ""
    writetolog "End of script"
    writetolog "**************************"
    exit $rc
}
Else
{
    writetolog $CodeDeRetour
    writetolog 'The script has failed'
    writetolog ''
    writetolog "**************************"
    writetoreg ('Fail',$rc)
    exit $rc
} 

}

Function writetoreg($status){

try
{
$date = Get-Date
$status_rc = 'RC = ' + $status[1]
$regpath_DT = 'hkcu:software\MyCompany\Applications\CopyTNSNames_1.0\Result'

if(!(Test-Path $regpath_DT)) {New-Item -Path $regpath_DT -force}

If($status[0] -eq 'Succes')
{
$result = 'Succes'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath_DT -Name $result -Value $date
}

If($status[0] -eq 'Failure')
{
$result = 'Failure Timestamp ' + $date 
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath_DT -Name $result -Value $status_rc
} 
}
catch [System.Exception]
{
   writetolog "Impossible d'écrire dans la base de registre, fonction writetoreg"
   $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
   $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
   writetolog "Erreur détectée...Détail : $ErrorMessage, $FailedItem"
}


}



Function CopyOra
{
 Try 
 {

   $PathFolder = "\\partage\ORAFiles\Source"
   $DestinationFolder = "c:\Apps\Oracle\11.2\network\admin\"

   if (!(test-path $DestinationFolder))
   {
      New-Item $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory  | Out-Null
      writetolog "Created folder  $DestinationFolder"
   }


   $LOGFilesFound = get-childitem $PathFolder -file | where Extension -eq ".ora" | Sort Time -descending

   foreach ($LOGFile in $LOGFilesFound) 
   {
        writetolog "processing files: $($_.Name)"


        If ( Test-Path "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile") 
        {
            writetolog "fichier trouvé $DestinationFolder$LOGFile ... Copie de backup en cours."

            $newFileName ="{0}-{1:dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm}{2}" -f $LOGFile.BaseName, (Get-Date), $LOGFile.Extension

            copy-item "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile" "$DestinationFolder$newFileName"

            writetolog "$DestinationFolder$newFileName créé."

        } 
        else
        {
            write-host "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile non trouvé sur le poste"
            writetolog "$DestinationFolder$newFileName non trouvé localement."

            copy-item "$PathFolder\$LOGFile" "$DestinationFolder$LOGFile"
            writetolog "Copie effectuée de $PathFolder\$LOGFile"
        }


    }

 }

 Catch
 {
      $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
      $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
      writetolog "Erreur détectée...Détail : $ErrorMessage, $FailedItem"
      code_retour -1
 }

}

$ErrorActionPreference ='Stop'

cls

CopyOra 

code_retour 0
```

Comment: Hi and Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Seems that is not able to write on the registry.
2017-02-14 13:56:51    processing files: 
2017-02-14 13:56:51    c:\Apps\Oracle\11.2\network\admin\ non trouvé localement.
2017-02-14 13:56:51    Copie effectuée de \\partage\ORAFiles\Source\Tnsnames.ora
2017-02-14 13:56:51    Return code : 0
2017-02-14 13:56:51    Impossible d'écrire dans la base de registre, fonction writetoreg
2017-02-14 13:56:51    Erreur détectée...Détail : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Path », car il a la valeur Null., 


Kind Regards.

Comment: You hâve an explaination to your problème now. You cant write into this part of registre

Comment: i have modified my code for write into hkcu and not into hklm, try it

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate your time !!
Well, using Powershell as Admin and also using SCCM 2012 System Context account it should be able to write on HKLM. Otherwise if we are using HKCU, the registry will be created on the user's hive and for this case we should be using HKLM as this will be sent to a Citrix Server. No need to have HKCU entries on those machines. 
What do you think?
Kind regards.

Comment: I have tested also your new changes and here we go: 
The script creates the hive structure on HKCU... but inside "Result" it does not creates the key for (Success or Fail). I've tested both scenarios when the TNSNames file is present and absent from the folder. So, the script creates successfully the destiny path inside: C:\Apps....Admin\ but it sends no error message about the missing file on the log file. It finish giving Return Code = 0. But that was only for creating the folder inside C:\Apps\...  but the file copy didn't catch the return code.